# What is the Average Yield on High-Grade Corporate Bonds as of Now?

Tags: stocks, bonds, investment-strategies, corporation, value-investing

I am looking to update the formula used by Benjamin Graham to calculate a stock's intrinsic value. His most recent formula can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Graham_formula.

The formula contains the number 4.4, which was the average yield of high-grade corporate bonds in 1962, which was when this model was introduced.

I am trying to make the formula more relevant and updated via replacing 4.4 with the current average yield on high-grade corporate bonds.

Does anyone know what this number is, or where I can find it?

Thank you for your time. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That formula is no longer really usable. The definition of "high-grade" corporate bonds was AAA-rated, but only three US companies retain an AAA rating, which isn't really enough to get a meaningful average yield.

Comment: What formula `is` usable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yahoo! Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/bonds/composite_bond_rates) would list it as 3.30 for the 20 year corporate AAA bonds. This is using the criteria from the Wikipedia link you stated in the initial question.

Comment: where can I get this for eurozone high yield corporate bonds? -B -BB and C